# How to create calendar groups on outlook programmatically?

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

Is there a way to create calendar group on outlook using MAPI/VC++?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calendar group? As in "Calendar folder"?

Comment: [Calendar group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-view-or-delete-a-calendar-group-04fc64f2-b658-450b-8dce-dd27ed660570?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Is there a way to create [Calendar group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-view-or-delete-a-calendar-group-04fc64f2-b658-450b-8dce-dd27ed660570?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: As far as I know they are stored in the profile sections, but there is no group specific API. You can try o poke around with OutlookSpy (click IProfAdmin etc.) to see if you can spot anything.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to see the calendars added under the group in IProfAdmin section in Outlook spy. But i am not seeing any property related to calendar group. How do i create one? What PR_CONTAINER_CLASS should be used to create the group?

Comment: You would not see a property that screams "I am for a calendar group". Most likely it will be a nameless binary property with an entry id or some such.